# Make ethanol with sourdough

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, carbohydrates

I have seen a lot of videos on internet and to make ethanol they ferment sugar with yeast but is it possible to ferment sugar using sourdough ?

Comment: Seems like Seasoned Advice SE would be the right place for this?

Comment: Yes. BTW, a local bakery was forced to add filtering to remove alcohol vapor. Though I support smog reduction, it was regrettable to me that the luscious aroma of baking sourdough bread was removed, as well.  ψ (*heartfelt sigh*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially yes, according to [this sourdough site](https://thesourdoughclub.com/fermentation-explained/)

> When yeast breaks down glucose, it transforms it into carbon dioxide and ethanol, both by-products are formed in equal parts. So, for every glucose molecule, two molecules of carbon dioxide and two molecules of ethanol are formed.

Comment: OP is asking about sourdough culture which is a complex mixture including a lot of bacteria as well as multiple yeasts, so it would be good to address the effects of that diversity relative to a pure yeast culture as is often used for ethanol production

Comment: If you have ever smelled an overripe sourdough starter you will have no doubt that it contains quite a lot of ethanol.

Comment: @Andrew  You are correct, if you wish to contribute a second answer exploring this then be my guest